# $y'=y^2+y^{2000}$ solved by constant zero function only

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How could I show that the only function solving $$y'=y^2+y^{2000},\quad y(0)=0$$ is the constant zero function?

Comment: This will be a consequence of a general existence-uniqueness theorem.

Comment: Is there a direct method? We are at the very beginning of our lecture.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe you can start out by saying that $y$ has to be bounded by some number $a$ in a neighbourhood of $0$, then use the differential equation to get a bound on $y'$ in that interval, which will in turn give you a bound on $y$ using the mean-value theorem. If you do things right, this bound might be much smaller than the previous one. Then repeat the procedure indefinitely. If you can get the bounds to tend to zero over some fixed interval, then you'll have shown that $y$ is zero on some interval around $0$ of a certain length. Then keep repeating.

Comment: worth pointing out that $y(0) = 1$ gives something very different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that there exists $t_0$ such that $y_0 := y(t_0) \neq 0$.
Let us consider the case $t_0 > 0$ (the other being similar), and define
$$
\tau := \max\{t\in [0, t_0]:\ y(t) = 0\},
$$
so that $y(\tau) = 0$ and $y(t) \neq 0$ for every $t\in (\tau, t_0]$.

In the interval $(\tau, t_0]$ there holds
$$
\frac{y'(t)}{y(t)^2 + y(t)^{2000}} = 1.
$$
Integrating this relation in a interval $[s, t_0]$, with $t\in (\tau, t_0)$, and using the change of variables $z= y(t)$ at the l.h.s., we get
$$
\int_{y_0}^{y(s)} \frac{1}{z^2+z^{2000}}\, dz = s - t_0,
\qquad s\in (\tau, t_0].
$$
On the other hand, as $y(s) \to 0$ for $s\to \tau^+$, we get a contradiction, since the function $\dfrac{1}{z^2+z^{2000}}$ is not integrable in generalized sense in the interval $[0, y_0]$ (or $[y_0, 0]$ if $y_0 < 0$).

Answer (score 2):

Assume otherwise and first assume that $y(t_0)\ne 0$ for some $t_0>0$ (the case $t_0<0$ works similar).

For $0<c<\min\{1,|y(t_0)|\}$, let $$\tau(c)=\inf\{\,t>0\mid |y(t)|>c\,\}.$$ 
Then $0< \tau(c)<\infty$, and by continuity of $y$, $|y(\tau(c)))|=c$.
By the Mean Value Theorem,
$$|y'(\xi)|=\tau(c)c$$ for some $\xi\in(0,\tau(c))$.
So $$\tau(c)c=|y'(\xi)| =|y(\xi)^2+y(\xi)^{2000}|\le c^2+c^{2000}<2c^2$$ 
and hence $\tau(c)<2c$.
Now $c\to 0$ implies $\tau(c)\to 0$ and hence
$$|f'(0)|=\lim_{h\to0} \left|\frac{y(h)-y(0)}{h}\right|=\lim_{c\to 0^+}\frac{|y(\tau(c))-y(0)|}{\tau(c)}=\lim_{c\to 0^+}\frac{c}{\tau(c)}\ge \frac12$$
whereas we should have $f'(0)=f(0)^2+f(0)^{2000}=0$..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $y(t)=0$ is a solution to that initial value problem.

As the function $f(y)=y^2+y^{2000}$ is continuously differentiable, it is also locally Lipschitz and thus all solutions to initial value problems of the ODE $y'=f(y)$ are unique.

---

But in this case it might indeed be easier to invoke that for $t>0$ and $|y|<1$
$$
1\le\frac{y'}{y^2}\le 2
\\
t\le \frac1{y(0)}-\frac1{y(t)}\le 2t
\\
\frac{y(0)}{1-2y(0)\,t}\le y(t)\le\frac{y(0)}{1-y(0)\,t}
$$
which enforces uniqeness of the zero solution.